# SQLite Insert error due to SQLite Command {"SQLite error\r\nnear \"Values\": syntax error"}

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I'm receiving this error '{"SQLite error\r\nnear \"Values\": syntax error"}'.
with the following block of code.

```
    using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection())
    {
        connection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
        connection.Open();
        using (SQLiteCommand insertSQL = new SQLiteCommand(connection))
        {
            insertSQL.CommandText = "INSERT INTO BetaValues(Name, Values)  VALUES(@param1, @param2)";
            //insertSQL.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            insertSQL.Parameters.Add("@param1", DbType.String).Value = beta.Name.ToString();
            insertSQL.Parameters.Add("@param2", DbType.String).Value = beta.ValuesXML.ToString();
            insertSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

The data definition of my table is the following.

```
CREATE TABLE BetaValues (
    idBetaValues INTEGER     PRIMARY KEY,
    Name         STRING (20) NOT NULL
                             UNIQUE,
    [Values]     TEXT        UNIQUE
);
```

I've been trying to wrap my head around this error, but I can't find the reason why I'm receiving the previous error.

Comment: `Values` is a reserved word in SQL. You have to escape the name in your INSERT statement the same way you did in your CREATE statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `VALUES` is a SQL operator you need to use a delimited identifier to identify the column correctly. In SQLite you could to add square brackets `[ColumnName]` around the column name. Note that there are also [other quotes possible](https://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html). Have a look at the create query you've already written and modify your insert statement like

```
INSERT INTO BetaValues(Name, [Values]) VALUES(@param1, @param2)
```

to solve your problem.